# Android Studio Cannot launch AVD in emulator. /opt/sdk/tools/emulator: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Not be able to launch `emulator` in `Android Studio`.

I have updated my `SDK` some days ago.

Here is my current `SDK` details.

[image]

[image]

My current system is `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` with `32 Bit`.

I am having **`Android Studio v1.3.2`**.

**My problem is when I try to launch any `AVD` from `Android Studio` I get following error.**

[image]

I am not able to find out what is the problem ! For your reference I can able to run the `Application on real device`.

The problem is only related to `emulator`.

Any help will be appreciated.

***Please help me if anyone knows about this i am still facing same problem. Not be able to solve it anyhow.I have tried some of the solutions of SO but it didn't solved for me.***

Comment: I am facing the same problem, Some solution below suggest that replacing the platform tools with older one, But this problem actually due to Android sdk tools not platform tools

Answer (score 4):

It's because of Linux 32 bit os. I solved this issue replacing old platform tool instead of updated.
following steps you need to perform: 
1) download and take old platform tool
2) remove existing platform tool.
3) add old platform tool 
4) restart android studio.

now it work fine and you can open emulator without error.

Also if you replace os to 64bit then good for future updates.

Comment: You can download platform tool for linux 32bit  here
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip

Comment: I am facing the same problem, Your solution suggest that replacing the platform tools with older one, But this problem actually due to Android SDK tools not platform tools

Comment: The tools (not platform-tools) link is https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip

Answer (score 1):

Its is because the android emulator doesn't like linux 32 bits. try to create a new Os 64bits.